# Fletcher's Checksum for arbitrary length group of bytes

Tags: c++, c, memory, checksum, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement a function to calculate an 8-bit Fletcher's checksum for a variable length region of memory, the idea being that I could pass a 2-byte short, or a 2kb array and use the same function. I've only been researching it today, so I'm definitely no expert on checksum algorithms or pointer arithmetic, and my code is almost certainly full of errors.

Basically my strategy is to pass a pointer to the address of the first byte in the group, as well as the size of the memory region to be scanned, and as long as the size is always sizeof(object being passed), it will be valid. I could calculate sizeof within the function to avoid potential errors, but I think I would have to restrict the type accepted to a particular type.

Now from what I understand, *(ptr + i), should return the value located in the ith byte after the address of ptr. I haven't done anything like this before though so I may have misunderstood what I read.

```
uint8_t fletcher_8(void *data, uint size){
        data = (uint8_t *)data; // Recast pointer as uint8_t*
        uint8_t sum1 = 0;
        uint8_t sum2 = 0; // Initialise variables for algorithm
        for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
            sum1 += *(data + i);     // get the value of the ith byte after the data pointer's address
            sum2 += sum1;
        }
        sum1 %= 16; // modulo the first sum
        sum1 << 4;  // shift lower four bits to the upper four bits
        sum2 %= 16; // modulo the second sum
        return sum1 + sum2; // add both sums (highest four bits are sum1, lower four bits are sum2
    }
```

If I've gone completely bonkers and there is any easier way to implement what I'm trying to do, I would love to hear it!

EDIT:

I *am* specifically asking about a C++ implementation, but the above code may as well be psudocode. I mostly want to know if my approach is correct more than anything.

Comment: What warnings do you get when you compile that code?

Comment: A couple notes: How many bytes does a void pointer (`data + i`) advance when incremented? `sum1 << 4;` likely dropped an `=`.

Comment: I should note I haven't been able to compile this as yet (at work). I'm mostly concerned with whether my approach is accurate, but in terms of what I've got here, I'll try and compile it in a few hours when I get home and see what the compiler complains about!

Comment: When being accessed the pointer should have been cast to a uint8_t type pointer (first line of the function), which to my understanding should be 1 byte.

Comment: I haven't used bitshifting before, so my syntax is probably buggered, but I basically want the line to be "move the bottom four bits of sum1 to the top four".

Comment: "I haven't been able to compile this as yet"  --> Suggest compiling first and trying it out.  Then if still having trouble, ask a SO question.

Comment: Like I said, I more wanted to confirm whether my _approach_ was correct more than anything.

Comment: This doesn't do anything: `data = (uint8_t *)data;`. Data will still be a `void*` after that line. If you want to cast to `uint8_t*` you need a new variable e.g. `uint8_t* u8data = (uint8_t *)data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version was better than the second one.

some mistakes in the second version:

- `data` should not be of type `void *`, otherwise `*(data + i)` is a compile time error. `data = (uint8_t *)data;` does nothing.
- `sum1 << 4;` misses a `=` to do anything: `sum1 <<= 4;`
- `i` and `size` should be of the same type. I prefer `size_t`, because it is the type `sizeof` returns.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum says that the higher bits should be `sum2`, yours are the bits from `sum1`.

I would write it like that

```
uint8_t fletcher_8(uint8_t *data, size_t size){
    uint8_t sum1 = 0;
    uint8_t sum2 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum1 += data[i];
        sum2 += sum1;
    }
    return (sum1 & 0xF) | (sum2 << 4);
}
```

or

```
uint8_t fletcher_8(uint8_t *data, size_t size){
    uint8_t sum1 = 0;
    uint8_t sum2 = 0;
    while (size--){
        sum1 += *data++;
        sum2 += sum1;
    }
    return (sum1 & 0xF) | (sum2 << 4);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help :) One thing: Wouldn't you need to take the modulus of the sums at some point?

Comment: `sum1 & 0xF` is the same as `sum1 % 16`. You do not need to do this for `sum2`, because the left shift fills in zeros and the msb will be shifted out of the range. For example: `0b11010101 << 4` will result in `0b01010000`